# Condition to open a specific report

Tags: ms-access

I am trying use coding instead of macro in MS Access to open a specific report. I have four reports and depending on the values on my table a specific report will be opened. The trouble is that I am receiving a TYPE MISMATCH message. I tried to use the same syntax as in the Macro Builder but it is not working. Find below the code. Any thoughts? Many thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub List201_Click()
  On Error GoTo err_list201_click

  Dim strDocName1 As String
  Dim strDocName2 As String
  Dim strDocName3 As String
  Dim strDocName4 As String
  Dim stLinkCriteria As String

  strDocName1 = "brokerClaimsMade1"
  strDocName2 = "brokerOccurrence2"
  strDocName3 = "nobrokerClaimsMade3"
  strDocName4 = "nobrokerOccurrence4"

  stLinkCriteria = "[geniusRefNumber] ='" & Me![List201] & "'"

  If "[brokerInvolved] = 1" And [wording] <> 2 Then
       DoCmd.OpenReport strDocName1, acViewPreview, , stLinkCriteria, acDialog
  ElseIf [brokerInvolved] = 1 And [wording] = 2 Then
       DoCmd.OpenReport strDocName2, acViewPreview, , stLinkCriteria, acDialog
  ElseIf [brokerInvolved] = 2 And [wording] = 2 Then
       DoCmd.OpenReport strDocName3, acViewPreview, , stLinkCriteria, acDialog
  ElseIf [brokerInvolved] = 2 And [wording] <> 2 Then
       DoCmd.OpenReport strDocName4, acViewPreview, , stLinkCriteria, acDialog
  End If

  exit_list201_click:
      Exit Sub

 err_list201_click:
      MsgBox Err.Description
      Resume exit_list201_click
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the data type for geniusRefNumber field? If it's Number, remove single quotes from stLinkCriteria

Answer (score 1):

```
If "[brokerInvolved] = 1" And [wording] <> 2 Then
```

Remove the double quotes - you are doing a logical AND of a string and a boolean expression.

```
If [brokerInvolved] = 1 And [wording] <> 2 Then
```

Comment: Many thanks for your replies. Appreciate it. geniusRefNumber is a text field e.g. XSG0001234LI16A. I have removed the double quotes and now I get a new error message: Microsoft Access can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression. Not sure how to handle this error.

Comment: Dear all. Problem solved. I used the column values on my list instead of database fields. It worked fined. E.g.: If List201.Column(7) = 1 And List201.Column(8) <> 2 Then